# struts2 edit or update after checked the check box

Tags: jsp, struts2

I previously use a table with a list of hotels with options in every row like

```
   hote name        hotelabbr               phnno                 option
    abc                ab                  23345345345            edit   delete
    def                abc                 34543534543            edit   delete
```

But now I have a table with a list of hotels with a check box with every row like

i have a check box left to each row and have a hyperlink contain the url of action class

like `<a href="edithotel" >Edit</a>` 
i want to update particular row or delete row after check on check box like if want to delete something he have to check the checkbox then click on delete hyperlink.
Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: [What have your tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I am unable to understand the need of both delete hyperlink and checkbox together. Either you should have a common delete hyperlink at the top/bottom with checkboxes in each row to select rows to delete, or only delete links for each individual row. Why do you need both? what will happen if I chose checkbox of one row and click on delete of another row? Isnt it confusing? Also, you should post how are you genrating this list, are you using `<s:iterator>` tag?